# Common Lisp: how to display a dot?

Tags: common-lisp

I want to use the dot (.) as a symbol, like `a` or `b`.

I found that I can do so by quoting and escaping the dot. However, when the dot is displayed on the screen, it is surrounded by vertical bars:

```
'\.
=> |.|
```

How can I get the dot displayed without the vertical bars?

Update: Thank you jkiiski, using `format` works great. Here's why I am doing this: For my own education, I wrote a function to convert a list in list notation to the equivalent list in dot notation. Thanks to your help, now it works great:

```
(defun list-notation-to-dot-notation (lst)
    (cond ((atom lst) lst)
          ((null (cdr lst)) (list (list-notation-to-dot-notation (car lst)) '\. 'NIL))
          (t (list (list-notation-to-dot-notation (car lst)) '\. (list-notation-to-dot-notation (cdr lst))))))

(defun list-2-dot (lst)
    (format t "~a" (list-notation-to-dot-notation lst)))

(list-2-dot '(a))
=> (A . NIL)

(list-2-dot '(a b))
=> (A . (B . NIL))

(list-2-dot '((a) b))
=> ((A . NIL) . (B . NIL))

(list-2-dot '(a (b) c))
=> (A . ((B . NIL) . (C . NIL)))

(list-2-dot '(a b (c)))
=> (A . (B . ((C . NIL) . NIL)))

(list-2-dot '((a) (b) (c)))
=> ((A . NIL) . ((B . NIL) . ((C . NIL) . NIL)))
```

Comment: Printing it without the bars would be ambiguous (for example, is `(1 . 2)` a cons cell or a list of three elements). If you print it with `format` using the `~a` directive it won't have vertical bars, but I don't think there is any situation where that would be useful.

Comment: Use the function `PRINC`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a bit cleaner way of achieving the same result:

```
(defun print-dot-notation (list &optional (stream *standard-output*))
  (if (atom list)
      (format stream "~s" list)
      (format stream "(~a . ~a)"
              (print-dot-notation (car list) nil)
              (print-dot-notation (cdr list) nil))))

(print-dot-notation '(a (b) c))
; (A . ((B . NIL) . (C . NIL)))
```

No need to create extra lists or use a symbol for the dot.

Comment: Wow! Very nice. Thank you jkiiski!

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be the simplest solution to the case:

```
(defun list-notation-to-dot-notation (list)
  (cond ((atom list) (format t "~S" list))
        (t (format t "(")
           (list-notation-to-dot-notation (car list))
           (format t " . ")
           (list-notation-to-dot-notation (cdr list))
           (format t ")"))))
```

as found in *Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation* by professor David S. Touretzky.

Assume you have a function, `list-notation-to-dot-notation`, that you know it converts lists from list notation to dot notation, *i.e.*:

- prints the `car` of the list `(car list)`
- prints a dot `.`
- and prints the `cdr` of the list `(cdr list)`

Then, all you have to do is to recursively call that function on the `car` and on the `cdr` to convert them to dot notation, and putting a dot in between.

Personally, I find the base condition to be a bit tricky.
As you can't simply write `(cond ((atom list)`**`list`**`)) ...` as it wouldn't print atoms correctly (at all!), perhaps due to the fact the return value will be passed to `format`.

Answer (score -1):

Just FYI, the lisp printer will always print the dot (.) symbol as `|.|` because the dot is associated with special, lisp reader defined rules. Unless it is part of the name like `foo.bar`, the reader will always assume you meant a dotted list of some kind.